# IP or Subnet based blocking in Spring Cloud Zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, api-gateway

I want to allow specific ip addresses or a subnet mask to access my endpoints. I am currently using sprind clud Zuul as an API gateway which offers blocking a specific URL or a pattern. Eg :

```
 zuul:
    ignoredServices: '*'
    routes:
       users: /myusers/**
```

> In this example, all services are ignored except "users".

Here is the Document: [Zuul Router and Filer](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.x/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html)

I want a similar functionality which could allow only specific ip addresses or perhaps a subnet mask (As cloud instances my get different ips over time) which would be called from own cloud enviroment and not exposed to the world.

Is there any way to achive this in Spring data Zuul ?

Comment: There is not a built-in way to do this. You would need to write a custom filter.

Comment: @spencergibb Yes. I have implemented a custom filter for it.